# Behavior of program changes depending on where fork is called

Tags: c, linux, unix

I was working on a little program getting familliar with pipes and file descriptors and spent a lot of time debugging a problem that does not make sense.

I spent a ton of time thinking I misunderstood file descriptors when it was just the program behaving differently depending on where I used fork.

```
int main(void)
{
int fid;
int p[2];
pipe(p);
char buf[20];

fid = fork();
if (fid==0){
    close(p[1]);
    dup2(p[0],0);
    close(p[0]);
    execlp("cat","cat",(char *)NULL);

}
else{
    close(p[0]);
    dup2(p[1],1);
    close(p[1]);
    execlp("ls","ls",(char *)NULL); 
}

return 0;
}
```

Gives me the expected output of whats in that directory. ls out put gets piped to cat.

If I move the fork line above pipe(p); I wont get any output. I don't understand why that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're wondering why this works:

```
pipe(p);
fid = fork();
```

and this doesn't:

```
fid = fork();
pipe(p);
```

The reason is pretty straightforward: In the first case, the process creates a pipe, then splits into two (and both processes have access to the pipe).

In the second case, the process splits into two, and then each of the two processes creates its own pipe that's unrelated to the other one.

So in the first case, one process writes to a pipe and the other process reads from it. In the second case, one process writes to a pipe and the other process reads from *a different pipe*, which obviously hasn't received the data because it's a different pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The `fork` system call creates an exact duplicate of the process which called it. This includes any file descriptors. With the `fork` call where it is now, each process has the ends of the pipe created via your `pipe` call. This is why each process closes a different end of the pipe and then one process calls `dup2` to hook the pipe to `stdout` while the other hooks the pipe up to `stdin`. This is how the processes communicate. But if `fork` is called before the `pipe` call, each process has created its own independent pipe.